# ggplot2: Finding f(x) for geom_step

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to use the aesthetic created by ggplot2's geom_step function to find f(x) for a given x?

I've plotted a step function representing a time series, and I'd like to plug in an x value and return the y value represented by the step function, and the only other way I can think of is to derive the most recent incident prior to the x value I'm looking for.  Is there a way to do this using the ggplot object?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "can I extract ... from ggplot?" is *usually* "it's easier to recapitulate the computation outside of ggplot".  In this case, the answer is `approxfun(x,y,method="constant")` (from the `stats` package in base R).

```
dd <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=1:5)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd,aes(x,y))+geom_step()

ee <- approxfun(dd$x,dd$y,method="constant")
```

Recapitulate ggplot:

```
curve(ee,from=1,to=5,type="s")
```

Examples of use of the function:

```
ee(1.5)
ee(3.9)
```